# how to convert Decimal numbers to ASCII?

Tags: flutter

Hello i want to convert a decimal number to ASCII so this the code i parse my string to int then i call the function String.fromCharCode to convert  the int to decimal . But it doesn't work any help ! thanks

```
 String payload ="47, 50, 48, 50, 50, 59, 49, 52, 58, 51, 52, 59, 48, 55, 47, 58, 5";
 print (payload);
for (var i = 0; i < payload.length; i++)
          {
            print (payload[i]);
            data = String.fromCharCode(int. parse(payload[i])) + data ;
          }
print(data);
```

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
for(int i=65; i<=90; i++){
  print("${String.fromCharCode(i)}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

okay so this how it works for me

```
String payload ="47, 50, 48, 50, 50, 59, 49, 52, 58, 51, 52, 59, 48, 55, 47, 58, 5";

final splitted = payload.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length ; i++)
          {
            print (splitted[i]);
            data = String.fromCharCode(int.parse(splitted[i])) + data ;
          }
print(data);
```

Comment: While this works, it's a very inefficient to build a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to split your `String` into tokens, parse those individually, and then create a `String` from the parsed integer values.

```dart
void main() {
  String payload =
      "47, 50, 48, 50, 50, 59, 49, 52, 58, 51, 52, 59, 48, 55, 47, 58, 5";
  var s = String.fromCharCodes(payload.split(',').map(int.parse));
  print(s);
}
```

I'll also point out that an ASCII value of 5 ([ENQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enquiry_character)) is very suspect.